# Submitting a form with submit() using Promise

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to write something that could do the following in that particular order: (1) submit a form (2) print "Print me." (3) wait 3 seconds (4) print "Print me too."

**Why doesn't my code accomplish this?**

```js
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));}
function submitForm() { return new Promise(resolve => document.getElementById('form').submit());}

async function test() {
    wait submitForm();
    console.log("Print me.")
    wait sleep(3000);
    console.log("Print me too.")
};

test();
```

```html
<form id="form" type="hidden">
    <input value="" id="id" type="text">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript can't run through a form submission. That causes the browser to navigate to a new page (or at least a new copy of the page), which interrupts and unloads all of the scripts. – Consider using Ajax to "submit" the form in the background (ref: MDN - [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Sending_form_data))

Comment: Sure it can. A form submit can return a file download. So the page can still be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

- I think you wanted to say `await` instead of `wait` ?
- In `submitForm`, your `resolve` function was never called, see my correction below

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

function submitForm() {
  return Promise.resolve(() => document.getElementById('form').submit())
}

async function test() {
    await submitForm();
    console.log("Print me.")

    await sleep(3000);
    console.log("Print me too.")
}

test()
```

```html
<form id="form" type="hidden">
    <input value="" id="id" type="text">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The form doesn't get submitted by the looks of it. I am not sure what could cause that.  Thank you for your help to this point!

Comment: how can i handle when form submit gives 404 error ?

Comment: `.catch(..)`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch.